# Opencv Make White Pixels brighter than other pixels in the image so that to be displayed after thresholding

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have this image which has a white line and I'm trying to make this line more brighter so that it will be displayed clearly after Thresholding as shown in the expected Output. However with my code it's not able to detect the line.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
img = mpimg.imread(filenm)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

mask_white = cv2.inRange(img, (200,200,200), (255, 255, 255))
mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, (15,60,20), (25, 255, 255))
color_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_white, mask_yellow)
mask_img[color_mask == 0] = [0,0,0]

# apply image thresholding
img = cv2.bitwise_and(mask_img[:,:,0], masked_img[:,:,0], mask=stencil)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 130, 145, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# plot image
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap= "gray")
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HSV-Color-Picker](https://github.com/alieldinayman/HSV-Color-Picker/blob/master/HSV%20Color%20Picker.py) for finding the upper and lower color inputs for the `inRange` method.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("NPmF8.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lwr = np.array([16, 23, 129])
upp = np.array([36, 43, 209])
img_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upp)
```

Result:

[image]

Then you can apply `line-detector` to detect the lines:

```py
lines = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(img_mask)

for ln in lines:
    x1 = int(ln[0][0])
    y1 = int(ln[0][1])
    x2 = int(ln[0][2])
    y2 = int(ln[0][3])
    cv2.line(img,
             pt1=(x1, y1),
             pt2=(x2, y2),
             color=(0, 255, 0),
             thickness=3)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference using Hough Transform for detecting lines than line-detector?

Comment: I just want to give an example of how you can use it. You can also use Hough Transform. From my past experience, Hough transform performs worse than the `line-detector`. Therefore I used `line-detector` as an example.

Comment: I have multiple frames in different light conditions. the hsv is not constant. How should I find the hsv for all those frames?

Comment: Then you need to remove the lightning effect from the photo. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592160/preprocessing-methods-for-face-recognition-in-python/63620875#63620875), which combines `gaussianBlur` with `divide` method.